# Accessing github on ubuntu through squid proxy

Tags: proxy, github

I am not able to clone a particular github branch !
It shows following error when I try to do so.

```
           Cloning into 'ws'...
           error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://github.com/abcd/efg.git/info/refs
           fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

try setting http_proxy and https_proxy prior to running git, it should honor these environment variables:

```
export http{,s}_proxy=http://your.squid.server.ip:3128
git whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

407 is a Proxy Auth Required exception. If your proxy requires a username/password, you would need to provide it in order for Git to route the request through your proxy, either each time, or through some configuration you export